# Transform an array of arrays into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the (dynamic) input array:

```
[
 [1,"Node 1"],
 [2,"Node 2"],
 [3,"Node 3"],
 [4,"Node 4"]
//, Here the elements are going to appear
]
```

Can it be transformed to this?

```
[
 {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
 {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
 {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
 {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
 {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
//, Here the elements are going to be add
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the code you are looking for

```
const a = [
   [1,"Node 1"],
   [2,"Node 2"],
   [3,"Node 3"],
   [4,"Node 4"]
]

let objArray = []


a.forEach(element => {
  let obj = {}

  obj.id = element[0]
  obj.label = element[1]

  objArray.push(obj)
  return element
})

console.log(objArray)
```

Comment: I also built a [codepen](https://codepen.io/robertfedus/pen/yLNREjQ?editors=0002) of this.

Comment: We store the array we need to transform in the variable called "a", then we declare "objArray" as the final array we want to build. We loop through the elements of "a" with the forEach method (see [this](https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c)). Then we declare a temporary object in which be build "{id: 1, label: 'Node 1'}". Then we to objArray.push(obj) to push, to create a new entry in our final array. Then we just console.log it.

Comment: Hi again, thanks a lot! it works on codepen perfect. I tested in Google App Script and i get the following result: 

[
 {label=Node 1, id=1.0},
 {label=Node 2, id=2.0},
 {label=Node 3, id=3.0},
 {label=Node 4, id=4.0}
 ] 

Do you have any idea what is the cause of the equals instead the two dots? Thanks again!

Comment: I think it's their way of showing object, using "=" instead of ":". But can I get a link of that to make sure?

Comment: To have the backup: I share the Google Spreadsheet + Google Apps Script link, and we use: var obj = JSON.stringify(objArray); to get the correct format and remplace de = with : Thanks Robert!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner

```js
const elements = [
 [1,"Node 1"],
 [2,"Node 2"],
 [3,"Node 3"],
 [4,"Node 4"],
 // Here the elements are going to appear
]

map(fork({ id: get(0), label: get(1) }))(elements) /*
=> [
 {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
 {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
 {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
 {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
 {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'},
]
*/
```

[map](https://github.com/richytong/rubico#map), [get](https://github.com/richytong/rubico#get), [fork](https://github.com/richytong/rubico#fork)